# How to initialise an OutputStream with a Url?

Tags: ios, swift, file, stream, ios-app-group

I try to create an OutputStream to an app group folder, which is created as follows:

```
 func createProjectDirectoryPath(path:String) -> String
    {
        let containerURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.xyz")
        let logsPath = containerURL!.appendingPathComponent(path)
        NSLog("12345- folder path: %@", logsPath.path)

        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: logsPath.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            NSLog("12345- Unable to create directory %@", error.debugDescription)
        }
        return logsPath.path
    }
```

This function gives me a path like this

```
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/40215F20-4713-4E23-87EF-1E21CCFB45DF/pcapFiles
```

This folder exists, because the line FileManager.default.fileExists(path) returns true. The next step is to append a generated filename to the path, which I am doing here

```
let urlToFile = URL(string: createProjectDirectoryPath(path: "pcapFiles").appending("/\(filename)"))
```

which gives me the correct new path

```
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/40215F20-4713-4E23-87EF-1E21CCFB45DF/pcapFiles/39CC2DB4-A6D9-412E-BAAF-2FAA4AD70B22.pcap
```

If I call this line, `ostream` is always nil

```
let ostream = OutputStream(url: urlToFile!, append: false)
```

Do I miss something? The OutputStream should create the file on this path, but for unknown reason, it is not possible.

PS: AppGroup is enabled in Capabilities and in developers console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `createProjectDirectoryPath()` function returns a file *path,*
therefore you must use `URL(fileURLWithPath:)` to convert that to an 
`URL`. Alternatively, modify your function to return an `URL` instead:

```
func createProjectDirectoryPath(path:String) -> URL? {
    let containerURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.xyz")
    let logsURL = containerURL!.appendingPathComponent(path)
    do {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: logsURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        NSLog("Unable to create directory %@", error.debugDescription)
        return nil
    }
    return logsURL
}
```

In addition, you have to call `open()` on all `Stream` objects before
they can be used, this will also create the file if it did not exist
before:

```
guard let logsURL = createProjectDirectoryPath(path: "pcapFiles") else {
    fatalError("Cannot create directory")
}
let urlToFile = logsURL.appendingPathComponent(filename) 
guard let ostream = OutputStream(url: urlToFile, append: false) else {
    fatalError("Cannot open file")
}
ostream.open()
```